# How to add and subtract column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract two columns in my data frame and add a new column called delta to represent this

I tried the below code but I get the below error message:

```
KeyError: 'Tday'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3VSa.png) here is my data

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("P:\\Operators\\Matt\\Python\\ResidualLoad1.csv",encoding='latin1')
df['delta'] = df['Tday'] - df['DA']
print(df)
```